# Why is ruby plugin version 2.7.6 missing the pod command?

Tags: asdf-vm

It seems that the ruby plugin `2.7.6` is missing the `pod` command. Is this an issue or error or is there a specific reason why about that?

At first I was thinking that `asdf reshim ruby` doesn't work, but then I realized that the `pod` command is actually missing.

I also tried to uninstall and reinstall `ruby 2.7.6` but the installation is always the same, with a missing `pod` command.

[image]

I ended up copying the `pod` command from `2.7.5` to `2.7.6`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to run `gem update`.